# ¿Como conocer la cantidad de strings en un String[]?

Tags: java, string

Hola tengo el siguiente problema, estoy creando una clase para que el manejo de archivos me sea más amigable para una app que estoy creando.

La cuestión es que al intentar crear un método personalizado para leer y tabular los datos de un *txt* en un `String[]` necesito saber alguna función que me cuente cuantos hay almacenados antes de `null`.

Antes en una versión anterior de la clase que estoy creando usaba esta forma:

```
String[][] leido = new String [2][9999];
String lineaActual = "";

try
{
    FileReader f = new FileReader(txt);
    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(f);

    for (int i = 0; lineaActual != null ; i++)
    {
        try {lineaActual = buffer.readLine();}
        catch (IOException e) {System.out.println(e.getMessage());}

        leido[0][i] = lineaActual;
        leido[1][0] = Integer.toString(i); //Aqui almacenaba el limite de los String

    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {System.out.println(e.getMessage());}

return leido;
```

Disculpen mi terrible código de novato poco a poco lo intento sanear con la nueva versión que estoy haciendo pero necesito saber alguna funcion que me ayude con la cuenta para no tener que usar un `String[][]` sino un `String[]`.

Comment: probaste con `array.length`?

Comment: Si, pero me da directamente el valor del limite del array y lo que busco es que me de el numero de espacios realmente ocupados en el array

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] leido = new String [10000]; 
String lineaActual = "";
try
{
   FileReader f = new FileReader(txt);
   BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(f);
   int contador = 0; // Inicializa contador
   while (lineaActual != null) // Cuenta hasta que encuentra Null
   {
       try 
       {
          lineaActual = buffer.readLine();
          leido[contador] = lineaActual; // Uso contador de indice, en vez de crear una variable mas, lo cual tambien se podria hacer, pero es mas "eficiente".
          contador++; // Aumenta el contador solo si no se arrojo excepcion, es decir si se leyo algo.
       }catch (IOException e)
       {
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
   }
}catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
return leido;
```

Espero que esto sea lo que usted pregunta, esta medio confuso el tema de su codigo en la parte de leido [1][0] = ... y la variable readed que usas en el return no se sabe que es, podrias incluir el codigo completo incluida signatura del metodo
Tambien puedes usar ArrayList que te simplifca el llevar un contador como hice en mi caso, que en realidad usando el metodo Array.length te da la longitud de dicho arreglo: leido.length

Comment: Disculpa, por mi error la variable readed era en realidad la que yo cambie a leido para que fuera mas legible el codigo

Comment: entonces ahi modifique mi codigo para que readed sea leido, te sirvio lo que puse?